# How can I batch process Camtasia Studio's .camrec files?

Tags: windows, batch, video-conversion, camtasia

I have several Camtasia Studio's .camrec files. I would like to convert each of them to a .mp4 file, using the same conversion settings (audio/video encoding parameters, etc.). How can I achieve that without having to convert them one by one?

I use TechSmith Camtasia 8.3.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Batch process Camtasia Studio's .camrec files

As per [Convert Multiple Videos at once to MP4's](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/convert_multiple_videos_at_once_to_mp4s), there seems to be an option within [Camtasia Studio](https://www.techsmith.com/video-editor.html) that can perform the batch conversions of `.camrec` files to `.mp4` files.

> You can access Batch Production under the `Tools` **>** `Sharing`
>   **>** `Batch Production` menu option in **Camtasia Studio**.

[image]

<sub>[Image Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zltbhPZwOc4)</sub>

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Batch Produce Videos in Camtasia Studio 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zltbhPZwOc4)